# How to force object destruction when removed from an itemscontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I have scanned the net, but have been unable to find an answer.

I'm using a MVVM pattern with an ItemsControl to populate my display as:

```
           <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding CharacterEditors}" >
                    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                            <Canvas />
                        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
                    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Left" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasLeft}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Top" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasTop}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Height" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasHeight}" />
                            <Setter Property="Canvas.Width" Value="{Binding Path=CanvasWidth}" />
                        </Style>
                    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                </ItemsControl>
```

where in the viewmodel, the CharacterEditors are:

```
    private ObservableCollection<CharacterEditorViewModel> characterEditors;
    public ObservableCollection<CharacterEditorViewModel> CharacterEditors              
    {
        get
        {
            return characterEditors;
        }
        set
        {
            if (characterEditors != value)
            {
                characterEditors = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("CharacterEditors");
            }
        }
    }
```

Each CharacterEditor has its own view and viewmodel.

Now, I can remove a character editor from the list, as

```
 CharacterEditors.RemoveAt(2);
```

But, how can I force the destruction of that charactereditor view and viewmodel when the CharacterEditor is removed from the ItemsControl? That is, although that charactereditor is no longer viewed, I don't see where the Garbage Collector ever calls Finalize to destroy the object.

I am trying to immediately free-up resources from the usercontrol and viewmodel associated with the charactereditor that was removed-- and not wait for the garbage collector to get around to it--if it ever does.

Any help or ideas is most appreciated. Thanks.

Edit: using this as the destructor for a charactereditor shows that the destructor is not being called even after it has been removed from the ItemsControl list.

```
 ~CharacterEditorViewModel()   
       {
           Console.WriteLine("Finalizing CharacterEditorViewModel object");

}
```

Comment: *“I am trying to immediately free-up resources […] and not wait for the garbage collector to get around to it”* – Why?

Comment: If `CharacterEditors` implements `IDisposable` then just call `Dispose()` when you are done with it. Note that if you call `Dispose()`, a correct implementation of `IDisposable` will suppress the finalizer (i.e. it won't be called). If it doesn't implement `IDisposable`, then why does it implement a finalizer, and why do you think the finalizer should be called?

Comment: @poke Each charactereditor has its own inkcanvas and inkanalyzer with associated hints and events. Some of this (I think??) is tied up in unmanaged code. I want to be sure these resources are freed up when the charactereditor is removed from the list being displayed by the itemscontrol. Thanks.

Comment: @poke I might add, the inkcanvas is being used as a customcontrol within the usercontrol view displayed by the itemscontrol. The viewmodel for the customcontrol has no knowledge of the view (holding the customcontrol).  Does disposing of a viewmodel destroy its view??? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cleaning up the ViewModel is your responsibility:

```
var ce = CharacterEditors[2];
CharacterEditors.RemoveAt(2);
ce.Dispose();
```

and that also implies that your VM should implement IDisposable. Do not add a destructor (Finalizer).

The View is best left to the Garbage Collector.

Comment: The problem here though is that the resources to be released are being held in a customcontrol that was instantiated by the xaml -- not in the viewmodel. Ideas?

Comment: I'm thinking I may need to add a special event and have the customcontrol listen for removal to release its resources. Any better way?

Comment: A (Custom) control shouldn't be holding resources. Is it your own?

Comment: yes. The Customcontrol derives from InkCanvas to which I added an InkAnalyzer upon creation of the customcontrol...it seemed the right thing to do. Is there a better way? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to immediately free-up resources from the usercontrol and viewmodel associated with the charactereditor that was removed

I dont think WPF implements **IDisposable** so the application needs to clean up itself.What you can do is use [Dispatcher_ShutdownStarted](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.shutdownstarted.aspx) to free up your resources.

Take a look at [http://geekswithblogs.net/cskardon/archive/2008/06/23/dispose-of-a-wpf-usercontrol-ish.aspx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.shutdownstarted.aspx)

Comment: That's the problem exactly. This would be the answer exactly except I am not trying to shutdown the application, only one (of many) usercontrols. Thanks.